# How to have a server to provide api in android device

Tags: javascript, android, rest

We have a WEB app in React JS and would like to call a Rest API that is built on Android.

The issue is when we send the POST command, the response is blocked by Browser because of CORS Pre-Flight.

How the header in OPTION response or POST response should be configured that our WEP APP can get the proper response from POST and the browser does not cut that off.

I searched a lot but unfortunately could not find a proper solution for that.

I even added the following to accept "POST" request but I could not get the response back:

```
response.addHeader(“Access-Control-Allow-Origin”,”*”);
response.addHeader(“Access-Control-Allow-Headers”,”*”);
response.addHeader(“Access-Control-Allow-Methods”,”*”);
response.addHeader(“Access-Control-Expose-Headers”,”*”);
```

I would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use Retrofit for API calls in an android project, it'll save a huge amount of debugging time and it will manage errors.
[Link to a Retrofit Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial)

There's a dozen of other tools like this, but this seems to set and work easily.